# invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'

Tags: c++

Have a code as shown below. I have problem passing the arguments.

```cpp
stringstream data;
char *addr=NULL;
strcpy(addr,retstring().c_str());
```

`retstring()` is a function that returns a string.

```
//more code
printfunc(num,addr,data.str().c_str());
```

I get the error

> invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'.
>
> initializing argument 3 of 'void Printfunc(int, char*, char*)'on argument 3 of the function

on the above line. The function is called as shown below

```
void Printfunc(int a, char *loc, char *stream)
```

please  let me know if I need to change any initialization.

Comment: Compiler wants you to change char *stream to const char *stream

Comment: The answers below deal with the compilation error but you will also need to allocated some memory for the destination buffer passed to `strcpy` - you cant just past a NULL pointer as the destination argument

Comment: Calling `data.str().c_str()` is likely to have surprising results.

Comment: @Chad  You are right about that.. what _should_ work, doesn't... not reliably, anyway.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Well, `data.str().c_str()` yields a `char const*` but your function `Printfunc()` wants to have `char*`s. Based on the name, it doesn't change the arguments but merely prints them and/or uses them to name a file, in which case you should probably fix your declaration to be

```
void Printfunc(int a, char const* loc, char const* stream)
```

The alternative might be to turn the `char const*` into a `char*` but fixing the declaration is preferable:

```
Printfunc(num, addr, const_cast<char*>(data.str().c_str()));
```

Comment: It is very common in C libraries to have functions expecting a `char*` (or int*, float*, whatever) as an argument, even though `const char*` would be more appropriate, since the function does not try to modify the argument. In such cases (and they are the norm rather than the exception), you have no option but to use `const_cast<type*>()` to remove the const-ness. I can easily bet that developers wouldn't avoid const arguments in functions, if C/C++ had a less verbose way to declare them.

Answer (score 22):

`string::c.str()` returns a string of type `const char *` as seen [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/)

A quick fix: try casting `printfunc(num,addr,(char *)data.str().c_str())`;

**While the above may work, it is undefined behaviour, and unsafe.**

Here's a nicer solution using templates:

```
char * my_argument = const_cast<char*> ( ...c_str() );
```

Comment: First problem is using a cast to remove constness. Second problem is using a C style cast.

Comment: Thanks, I'm rusty. I'll update my solution. OP refer to @Dietmar's response

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, and a C-style cast doesn't really remove the "const"ness of the string.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: can you exaplain why?

Comment: @MarcoSulla Not in a comment but feel free to research the topics.

Comment: Template one works fine. Its possibly the safest solution out there!

Answer (score 3):

First of all this code snippet

```
char *addr=NULL;
strcpy(addr,retstring().c_str());
```

is invalid because you did not allocate memory where you are going to copy retstring().c_str().

As for the error message then it is clear enough. The type of expression data.str().c_str() is const char * but the third parameter of the function is declared as char *. You may not assign an object of type const char * to an object of type char *. Either the function should define the third parameter as const char * if it does not change the object pointed by the third parameter or you may not pass argument of type const char *.

Answer (score 0):

c_str() will give you a const char *

For converting const char * to char * you can use strdup like this.

```
char * success = strdup(data.str().c_str());
```

also it will make a new malloc so it creates a duplicate.

so you need to do this

```
char * success = strdup(data.str().c_str());
printfunc(num, addr, success);
free(success);
```

Comment: strdup is not available from standard library before C23 and it returns a dynamically allocated string which needs explicit deallocation. You're creating memory leak.